# Execute function when Ajax for specific form is complete

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

How do I use `.ajaxComplete()` or (similar function) for a specific form? I tried the following code, but it executes when ANY Ajax call completes. I only want it to execute when the Ajax call for `#FormId` completes. Seems like there should be a simple solution, but I'm not finding it.

```
$('#FormId').ajaxComplete(function() {
    console.log("Ajax call for #FormId completed");
});
```

Comment: Can you include `js` where `$.ajax()` is called on `#FormId` submission at Question ?

Comment: ajax has "success" callback function which is called when ajax request is completed successfully. You can also have a callback function when it is completed like this:  ajax().done(function() { });

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting `context` of `$.ajax()` to `this` within `submit` event for `#FormId` element, checking for `settings.context.id` at [`.ajaxComplete()`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxcomplete/#ajaxComplete-handler) event; where `settings` is third parameter or `ajaxOptions` originally passed to `$.ajax()`

```js
$(document).ajaxComplete(function(event, jqxhr, settings) {
   // if `settings.context.id` is equal to `FormId`, do stuff
   if (settings.context.id === "FormId") {
     alert(settings.context.id)
   }
})

$("#FormId").on("submit", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
    context: this
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<form id="FormId">
  <input type="text" value="abc" readonly />
  <input type="submit" />
</form>

<form id="FormId1">
  <input type="text" value="123" readonly />
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score -1):

Use this way,

```
$('#FormId').onClick(function(){
 $.ajax({
  method: "POST",
  url: "someurl.php",
  data: { name: "Ghanshyam Katriya", location: "India" },
   complete: function(){
alert("ajax complete");   
}
 });
});
```

you can call any js script in complete section, it will execute only when ajax call will be complete.

Comment: `.onClick` is not a jQuery method

Comment: OP asked specifically for the ajaxComplete-function